# How to use GCD with Core Data by creating local context

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to process items and store it with coredata and GCD. I'm copying the mainContext to the localContext. I haven't get to the merging part yet, but it kept crashing on me. Here's my code:

```
dispatch_queue_t coreQueue = dispatch_queue_create("coreQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

NSMutableSet __block *sumManagedObjects=[NSMutableSet set];

int processorCount = (int) [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processorCount];

int __block limit = ceil((float)recordsToCreate.count/processorCount);
int loopCount = ceil((float)recordsToCreate.count/limit);
dispatch_apply(processorCount, coreQueue, ^(size_t i) {

    int startIndex = ((int)i)*limit;
    int maxIndex = (int)recordsToCreate.count;
    int endIndex = (startIndex + limit) < maxIndex ? (startIndex + limit) : maxIndex;
    int range = endIndex - startIndex;

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    [localContext setParentContext:self.mainContext];

NSSet *createdObjects=  [localContext insertWithEntityName:self.entityName withDataObjects:[NSSet setWithArray:[recordsToCreate subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, range)]]];

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [sumManagedObjects unionSet:createdObjects];
         NSLog(@"managed objects %tu start index %d end index %d size_t : %d, sum managed object : %tu thread %@", [createdObjects count], startIndex, endIndex, (int)i, [sumManagedObjects count], [NSThread currentThread]);
        if([sumManagedObjects count] == recordsToCreate.count) {
            [sumManagedObjects setValue:@YES forKey:ItemAttribute.someKey];[context save:nil];


                        }

    });
```

Here's the updated code:

```
dispatch_queue_t coreQueue = dispatch_queue_create("coreQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

NSMutableSet __block *sumManagedObjects=[NSMutableSet set];

int processorCount = 8;

int __block limit = ceil((float)recordsToCreate.count/processorCount);
int loopCount = ceil((float)recordsToCreate.count/limit);

NSLog(@"int count %d, record to create %tu", loopCount, recordsToCreate.count);

dispatch_apply(processorCount, coreQueue, ^(size_t i) {

    int startIndex = ((int)i)*limit;
    int maxIndex = (int)recordsToCreate.count;
    int endIndex = (startIndex + limit) < maxIndex ? (startIndex + limit) : maxIndex;
    int range = endIndex - startIndex;

     NSManagedObjectContext *privateManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [privateManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:privateManagedObjectContext];

    [privateManagedObjectContext insertWithEntityName:self.entityName withDataObjects:[NSSet setWithArray:[recordsToCreate subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, range)]]];

    NSLog(@"current thread %@ start index %tu end index %tu size_t : %d", [NSThread currentThread], startIndex, endIndex, (int)i );


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(self.cancelled) return;

        [privateManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            privateManagedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
            BOOL success = [privateManagedObjectContext save:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];



    });

});

- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {

[self.mainContext performBlockAndWait:^{
if(self.cancelled) return;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(self.cancelled) return;
    [self.mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification ];
});
}];}
```

Now I'm getting this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x7fb5c30c3700> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Any ideas? Did I block the resource correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Confinement support in core data has been deprecated.  You should use the core data `performBlock` API for managing synchronization among threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can not update a confinement context on a background thread and then pass the managed object results back to the main thread to do another update and save the context. All updates and the context save need to be done on the background thread. This is the meaning of confinement and you need to obey that confinement rule.

Comment: I've updated my code, but it's still crashing. Now I'm getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x7fb5c30c3700> was mutated while being enumerated.' Please see my updated code in the original post. Thanks!